# How to filter ng-repeat by property value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When iterating a list with `ng-repeat`, how can I add a condition/filter by a property of those items.

Example (of course there are several items in real world):

```
{"items":[{"type":"xxx"}]}
```

I only want to show the item where `type!='test'`.

The following just prints nothing:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | filter: (item.type != 'test')">
```

Whereas if I remove the filter, all items are printed, of course.

Also, if possible, how could I create a condition that checks for *multiple* `type` values not being permitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use a function in the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) expression.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "type": "xxx"
    }, {
      "type": "test"
    }];

    $scope.filterFn = function(value) {
       return value.type !== 'test';
    };
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterFn">{{item.type}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If your data schema changes just update the filter function.

You could also use object notation

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      "type": "xxx"
    }, {
      "type": "test"
    }];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {type: '!test'}">{{item.type}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but this has some limitations like not suporting primitive value filters(it expects an object with properties as the item) and the same filter cannot be specified multiple times(something like `{type:"!test!xxx"}`)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `ng-repeat` to read like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {type: '!test'}">
```

In order to provide multiple `type` values you can create your own filter for reusability like so:

```
app.filter('typeFilter', function(){
  return function(arr,criteria){
    if(!angular.isDefined(criteria) || criteria == ''){
      return arr;
    }

    return arr.filter(function(curr){
      return criteria.indexOf(curr.type) == -1;
    });
  }
});
```

and then change your `ng-repeat` statement to read:

```
//List array of criteria...
<ul ng-repeat="item in items | typeFilter:['test'] ">
```

Comment: Great, and how could I add multiple "keywords" to test against in the filter?

Comment: Like  `filter: {type: ['test', 'xxx']}` but that does not work.

Comment: you'll have to create your own custom filter with a more elaborate filtering mechanism. You could used the native `filter` method to create a new array to display